# How to properly type static properties on memoized React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given the following example

How can I properly type or extend the existing return type of `React.memo`

```
const TestScreen = memo(() => <Text>Hello</Text>);

// Linter throws an error
// Property 'screenName' does not exist on type 'MemoExoticComponent<() => Element>'
TestScreen.screenName = 'ff';
```

Thank you

Comment: Never heard of `screenName`. Did you mean `displayName`?

Comment: I know `displayName` but this is my custom static property. @phry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const TestScreen: React.FC & { screenName?: String } = React.memo(() => {
  return <div>Test Screen</div>;
});
TestScreen.screenName = "My name";
```

Comment: This only works if screenName is optional which is not ideal. In my case i want the static property to be required (which works fine if not using React.memo)